# can't open snap store

Tags: snap, kali

no snap-store icon appears on the panel / menu.
so I try to open it through the terminal, I wrote down `sudo snap run snap-store` .
but still can't and there is writing like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBTOS.png.
my version of snapd is :

> snap    2.48.2-3

> snapd   2.48.2-3

> series  16

> kali    2020.4

> kernel  5.9.0-kali1-amd64

i'm using kali Linux

Comment: I think snaps (as well as non-snap apt packages) are now available through the normal Ubuntu `Ubuntu Software` GUI app. Search for something there and if it's available as a package and a snap then confusingly it will now show you both, but with no indication on which is which. You have to drill-down into the detail to see which one it is by looking at the `Source`.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snap-store` appears to be installed on your system.

You can run it like so:

```
snap run snap-store
```

Or like so:

```
snap-store
```

**Without `sudo`**, as using `sudo` to run GUI applications is **not a good idea** and will cause problems.

Please have a look at: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)